# IndexOutOfRangeException occured due to an if condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datatable, indexoutofrangeexception

An `IndexOutOfRangeException` just triggered in a little project I'm building, but why?

Here's the boolean condition:

```
(messages != null && messages.Rows[0] != null)
```

What I was trying to do is to check if these two objects were initialized, but as you already figured this happened all of a sudden.

Comment: Well presumably there are no rows...

Comment: modify it to read:  `(messages != null && messages.Rows.Count > 0 )`  or `(messages != null && messages.Rows.Count > 0 && messages.Rows[0] != null)`

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to check whether or not `Rows` is empty too. We don't actually know the type of `Rows`, but you might want:

```
if (messages != null && messages.Rows.Count > 0 && messages.Rows[0] != null)
```

Or you could use LINQ to get the first row if it exists, and check whether that's null:

```
if (messages != null && messages.Rows.FirstOrDefault() != null)
```

(That's assuming `Rows` implements `IEnumerable<T>` for some `T`.)

It's also possibly that `Rows[0]` will *never* be null, and you really *only* need to check whether the count is greater than 0:

```
if (messages != null && messages.Rows.Count > 0)
```

Or:

```
if (messages != null && messages.Rows.Any())
```

Comment: thanks, it worked! -- but why do you have to check if Rows is empty as well? it's just that it isn't, technically.